# Markdown - Multi checkbox in one line

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown

i have a issue with markdown in github comment.

```
- [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] item 1
- [ ] - [ ] - [ ] - [ ]item 2
```

With above code, only the first checkbox is ok :(

Comment: This would a really useful feature. I want two columns. One for checking off when an item is cleared for deletion, and another for when the item is verified "do not delete." Those unchecked are left to determine. I'm sure there are many other cases in gitlab/github workflows.

Answer (score 19):

The [documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/writing-on-github/#task-lists) makes no mention of supporting multiple checkboxes on one line. I suspect it is not possible. However, if you want to have multiple checkboxes for one item, you can create a nested list. Like this:

```
- [ ] item 1
    - [ ] item 1-1
    - [ ] item 1-2
    - [ ] item 1-3
    - [ ] item 1-4
- [ ] item 2
    - [ ] item 2-1
    - [ ] item 2-2
    - [ ] item 2-3
    - [ ] item 2-4
```

Answer (score 11):

Although there is no option for inline checkboxes using standard **[x]**,
you can use emoji for your purpose.

Here is the emoji code in markdown:

```markdown
:black_square_button: empty checkbox   
:ballot_box_with_check: completed checkbox 1   
:white_check_mark: completed checkbox 2    
:heavy_check_mark: completed checkbox 3
```

And the expected result:

[image]

Rendered as inline

[image]

Comment: Creative solution, Akash!