# How to add a checkbox within a markdown table in Gitlab?

Tags: checkbox, gitlab, markdown

I am trying to set up a table in markdown that I can store in a Gitlab Wiki.

The table looks something like this:

> | Col1 | Col2 | Col 3 | Col4 |
>
>  | :---: | :---: | :---: | --- |
>
>  | ID1 | Yes | No | some text |

Here is how the table looks:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col 3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | Yes | No | some text |

What I would like to do instead of editing and changing the cell to be Yes or No manually, that I could use a checkbox, normally "- [ ]" should work but apparently does not work inside of table.

Comment: Not exactly the same. But people coming here may also be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31694871/markdown-multi-checkbox-in-one-line.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be supported right now: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/21506